# Find a linear time algorithm that sorts n numbers from the interval [0,2] such that for each 2 numbers a,b : |a-b| > (1/n)^2

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I would really appreciate any help. This is the question:

Find a linear time algorithm that sorts n numbers from the interval [0,2] such that for each 2 numbers a,b :   |a-b| > (1/n)^2

The sad part here is that I read the answer to this question and still don't know how to solve it... Here is what they said:

For each number ai (assume i is the index), we will "attach" a number ni such that:
ni/2n2 <= ai <= (ni+1)/2n2

(This is exactly how they wrote it, I think they meant ni/(2n^2) and (ni+1)/(2n^2) but I'm not certain).
And then they said that it's not hard to show how to sort the numbers ni in linear time...

I understand why it's enough to show how to sort the numbers ni in linear time but I really have no idea how to do it...

It's really frustrating... :(

Comment: this is like radix sort except that your buckets are identified by ni/(2n^2) and (ni+1)/(2n^2)

Comment: Arguably it *is* hard to show how to sort the numbers in linear time. Radix sort is all very well, but the numbers `n_i` have up to `log(2n^2)` digits, which is not a constant term. I suppose you do it in 2 passes of `n` buckets each.

Comment: Thanks guys. I think a radix sort in base n would solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have attached numbers which are integers and from 0 up to 4n^2.

If you consider these in base 2n, then you have 2 digit numbers.

You can sort these using [radix sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort) which has complexity O(nk) where k is the number of digits.

In your case k=2, so the overall algorithm is O(2n)=O(n), i.e. linear.